# My Web and DNS Server both are on the same private network but DNS server has a public IP. How can I open my website from publically with DNS name

Tags: networking, dns, ip

My Web server and DNS Server both are on the same private network. The web server does not have any Public IP but DNS server is having a natted public IP. The DNS server is running on bind9. How can I open my web server from public DNS.

Private network is - 10.0.0.0/20

Web Server private IP - 10.0.14.167

DNS server private IP - 10.0.1.199

DNS server public IP - x.x.x.x

Here is my named.conf.options file configuration:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    recursion no;
    allow-transfer { none; };
    dnssec-validation auto;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    listen-on { any; };
    };
```

Here is my named.conf.local file configuration:

```
zone "1.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/zones/db.10.0.1";
```

};

```
zone "mydomain1.com" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/zones/db.mydomain.com";
```

};

```
zone "14.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/zones/db.10.0.14";
```

};

[Here is the db.10.0.1 file configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI1mE.png)

[Here is the db.10.0.14 file configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8oEm.png)

[Here is the db.mydomain.com file configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0YnV.png)

When I am trying to open php7.mydomain.com it is showing "This site can’t be reached, php7.mydomain.com refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Can anyone please help me out, I am in the deep shade.

Comment: In your router, you need to forward TCP port 80 to your web server.

Comment: Your A records for www.example.com and such need to point to your public IP, which should then forward the appropriate port(s) to your internal network.  I'd see what could be done about getting several public IPs...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply here, but we have only one Public IP on our DNS Server and we have multiple web servers on our private network. How can we access those via DNS name from publically?